# Purpose of Zookeeper in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, message-queue, apache-zookeeper

As from the latest consumer versions of Kafka, the consumers aren't dependent on ZooKeeper. But "https://kafka.apache.org/" says Kafka requires Zookeeper, so start zookeeper server. why is it so?. Once a topic has been created, even though I terminate Zookeeper it works. So the purpose of Zookeeper is only for creating a Topic? If so why not move creating Topic also to be independent of zookeeper

Answer (score 2):

Kafka topics (still) require Zookeeper for electing a leader, communicating server failure, and storing the list of topics, plus some extra metadata such as replica location and topic configurations.

Kafka Wiki - [How does Kafka depend on Zookeeper](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-HowdoesKafkadependonZookeeper?)

Confluent and the Kafka community are trying to move away from the Zookeeper dependency. For example, the Confluent Schema Registry can now use Kafka for leader election. Related blog from Confluent - https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-prepare-for-kip-500-kafka-zookeeper-removal-guide/

And in Confluent Cloud, Amazon MSK, and other hosted Kafka offerings, you generally have no access to Zookeeper at all.

Answer (score 0):

The consumers are not dependent on Zookeeper as they are client-side. Likewise with the producers.

Zookeeper is required for the Kafka brokers themselves. Kafka brokers use Zookeeper to co-ordinate and synchronise themselves.